# Как реализовать подобное

Tags: javascript

```
onmousemove
```

Получаем координаты курсора, относительно краев блока. Но что если в моменте когда курсор попадает на элемент и необходимо зажать левую кнопку мыши и при этом увести курсор с элемента.

Как выполнить так, чтобы координаты продолжали поступать, относительно кроев выбранного блока.

Данная задача необходима для того, чтобы выполнять перемотку на ползунке, который привязан к media, то есть выполнять таким образом перемотку.

Comment: [setPointerCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture)